Request/response on Facebook mobile cannot be captured by Chrome DevTool
I have an issue when trying to view XHR requests on the mobile version of Facebook. None of the requests/responses from Facebook are visible. This happens when the device is switched to a mobile version in Chrome DevTools, but when using the web version of Facebook, everything is visible. I have attached an image below.
I still haven't found any answers or ideas. I've done my best searching.
